# How to know whether a name exists on a particular sql table in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following table:

users: user_userName, user_userEmail, user_password.

What i want is to know whether the user name exists (if so, tell the user to create a new one, otherwise they'll be on user's table) after clicking a button on c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM users WHERE user_userName = @userName) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", connection))
{
    cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("userName", "TestUserName");
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(DBNull.Value.Equals(result) || result == null || (int)result == 0)
    {
        // user does not exist
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? He didn't say Linq. Count will always return in this instance.

Comment: EXISTS makes more sense than COUNT since the specific number isn't of interest.

Comment: Changed as per Habo's suggestion. I was going for the simple approach but guess that is better :)

Answer (score 2):

your approach has a little flaw in it, as you want to check 1st if a user account exists and if it doesnt then tell user to create one.

Imagine a scenario where UserA check for a UserName which doesnt exist then by the time UserA tries to Create a user what if another user comes in and creates the same user name  UserA was going to create (Trouble).

I would suggest design your application in a way that let you select the user name or get the user name that a user is trying to create and check it and create it straight away rather then waiting for user to create it once it has been checked for existence etc.

You can create a stored procedure for this purpose, something like this.....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Create_UserName
@UserName   VARCHAR(100),
@Email      VARCHAR(100),
@Password   VARCHAR(100),
@Message    VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE user_userName = @UserName)
     BEGIN
       SET @Message = 'User Name already Exist Please try a different User Name';
     END 
  ELSE 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Users (user_userName, user_userEmail, user_password)
       VALUES (@UserName,@Email,@Password);
      SET @Message = 'User Name is Created Happy Days :)';
    END   
END
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ it is something like below:

```
User user = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "John");
if (user != null)
{
    // Use user
}
else{
   // create a new one
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
if (db.users.Any(r => r.user_userName == login.Text))
    // todo: create user
else
    // use this user
```

Very readable and performant.

Comment: Yes.  However: it would be great if you could let us know how you're connecting to that database.  The wide variety of solutions is caused by some assumptions being made.

Comment: im connecting by System.Data.SqlClient, so i have a connectionString :p

Comment: You're using a method that most closely matches @John's answer.  use that one and (if you don't mind) mark it as accepted.

Comment: yeep! i just typed john's method and its working now!! thank you anyways jeffdot !! :D